# Issue with tidyr::spread and dplyr::mutate_each under lapply()

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am trying to use `tidyr::spread` and `dplyr::mutate_each` jointly in a piped structure, as in the following example:

```
df_new <- df %>%
   split(list(.$x, .$y, .$z, .$w), drop = TRUE) %>%
   lapply(function(x) {
               x %>%
                 spread(key = filename, value = value) %>%
                 mutate_each(funs(. - freefree), starts_with("NIData_"))
                       })
```

The code creates a list based on the combinations of `df`'s `x`, `y`, `z`, `w` columns, and applies `function(x)` to each element.

The `filename` column contains the value `freefree` and some other values starting with `NIData_` . 
The `mutate_each()` has the purpose of subtracting the column `freefree` from all columns starting with `NIData_`.

When I run the code I get a the following error:

> Error: object 'freefree' not found

Trying to debug the code, I limited it to the following commands:

```
df_new <- df %>%
       split(list(.$x, .$y, .$z, .$w), drop = TRUE) %>%
       lapply(function(x) {
                   x %>%
                     spread(key = filename, value = value)
                           })
```

If I now apply:

```
df_new[[1]] %>% mutate_each(funs(. - freefree), starts_with("NIData_"))
```

the `mutate_each()` is correctly executed. That is, it does not work if the `spread()` and `mutate_each()` sequence is run within an `lapply()` command, but it does if it is applied on a specific element of the list.

I know I should post a minimal working example but the dataframe I am working with is pretty large and difficult to emulate. Should it be possible (how?) and upon request, I would be happy to upload it for you to have a look if you feel that may help.

Regards and thanks.

Comment: If you just used `group_by`, you wouldn't need the `split` and `lapply`.

Comment: I can't reproduce on a simple example using dplyr_0.4.3.9001.  If you just run the first element from the `split` list through the pipe in `lapply` do you get the same error?

Comment: @alistaire I had already tried what you suggest, but I get the error message: `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 27.6 Gb` . That's why I had to go through the `split()`, `lapply()` method

Comment: @aosmith No, I don't. If `df_new` is the split dataframe and I then apply the pipe in `lapply` only to the first element of the list, I do not get the same error and everything goes through finely.

Comment: How big is this data.frame?

Comment: @alistaire 7742614 rows by 9 variables.

Comment: Given that the first split data.frame works, one possibility is that one of your splits is missing the variable for some reason.  To troubleshoot, you'll want to trace to the point of failure.  Maybe build a `tryCatch` into your function or run through a `lapply` loop that detects the variable after spreading.

Comment: There was a missing value indeed! Thank you so much for pointing that out to me!